# Track handle creation / deletion

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, windows-xp, handle

I have a large old program which has some rather complex graphical displays (all via standard API calls). The program appears to be working fine, but I recently looked at the "handles" field of Windows Task Manager when this program was running and noticed that the number of handles was gradually and relentlessly creeping upwards.

Is there some software or strategy I can employ to trace this rogue handle creation?

I Would expect the program to create a large number of handles, but I would also expect this to reach a limit. So what I really want to see is which part of the code was creating the *most recent* handles.

**EDIT:** After some investigation with "Process Explorer" I have discovered that the thing that is creeping up is "Handles" rather then "GDI Handles". So I guess that means its nothing to do with the complex graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/cdbntsd5.aspx) link for advice. Problem is complex and somebody has written tutorial on how to tackle it.
Update: [here](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.debugger/2005-11/msg00005.html) is one more link that can help.

Comment: Looks good, and the sysinternals "handle" program has shown me that the type of handle that is leaking is an "Event" handle. But I can't find an explanation of what that is... maybe I should start a separate SO question?

Comment: Well, I guess browse your code for OpenEvent function call without corresponding CloseHandle call. Chances are - there won't be many of such places (but called often)

Comment: There is not a single instance of openevent in my entire program :-(

Comment: How about CreateEvent or CreateEventEx ?

Comment: Please see update to my post. Sorry can not be of more help, not really familiar with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this problem is to use the [RAII design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

In which for every handle you create you wrap it in a class.

For example:

```
class CAutoHandle
{
public:
  CAutoHandle(HANDLE handle) : m_handle(handle)
  {
  }

  ~CAutoHandle()
  {
    CloseHandle(m_handle);
  }

  HANDLE m_handle;
};
```

---

@JaredPar also suggests another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318420/applicationverifier-is-not-detecting-handle-leaks-what-do-i-do/318502#318502) in which you redefine CreateFile to call your own function that has tracking.

Comment: Sadly its too late - the program is very old and very large - in fact its only very recently been changed form C to C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/memory/index.html) to find the handles leak. Try Eval version.

Answer (score 0):

Handles can be a lot of things, not just file handles but also GUI objects (quirks like creating an icon and deleting it with DeleteObject() rather than DestroyIcon()).

There's an MSDN article with various techniques:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx and a program package called Leaks.exe (assuming that you still can run your code under W95)

Comment: "Note that the tools in this article use techniques that are undocumented and are not supported by Microsoft."... Hmmm, maybe I should have said, I'm using XP. Do you think it will still work?

Comment: I think Handle count in task manager refers to kernel handles, not GDI's

Comment: Another problem is that the software (leaks.exe) appears not be be available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Other functions that create HANDLEs are CreateThread, OpenThread, CreateProcess, OpenProcess, CreateMutex, OpenMutex, LoadLibrary and possibly InitializeCriticalSection (not sure about that one).

I don't know if these qualify as event handles in that tool which you are using but they may be worth checking.